# React / MaterialUI - import and export with the same name

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create component with name "Menu" and import "Menu" from MaterialUI, something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';

class Menu extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Menu>
                    ...
                </Menu>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

How can I do this? I tried to do with import { Menu as OtherName} etc but all time I have errors.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

```
import { default as materialMenu } '@material-ui/core/Menu';
```

or

```
export { myComponent as Menu };
```

Comment: Glad to help! 
Welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Below are the two scenarios of exporting and importing

If you export a component with default then you can import the component as

```
   import Menu from ‘./Menu’;
```

Export with default:

```
   export default class Menu extends Component{
       ........

       ........
   }
```

If you export a component without default then you can import the component as

```
   import {Menu} from ‘./Menu’;
```

Export without default:

```
   export class Menu extends Component{
       ........

      ........
   }
```